# Class Methods : Override my methods in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, class, overriding

if I have class :

```
public class myclass{

    public int calc(int var1,int var2){
        return var1*var2;
    } 

    public int calc(int var1 ,int var2 , int var3){
        return var1*var2/var3;
    }
 }
```

Question is: is there any way if I want to override any method of my class

Example: I just made `myclass extends Async` and the doInBackground generate with the @Override annotation...

More Explain:

```
class  ares extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {
    @Override
    protected Result doInBackground(Params... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }   
}
```

I want when I made `Sub Class extends myclass` -> that `calc` method generates like doInBackground.

Comment: are you talking about inheritance like here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html ?

Comment: Thanks James , but I had read this tutorial but the missing thing is when i made sub class extends myclass the compiler never ask me to add unimplemented methods like in AsyncTask .. so i ask what is changes must be do to compiler understand 'calc' method is implement method .. i think now its clear ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotation `@Override` is not mandatory but optional and can be added automatically by your formatter of Eclipse.

It is also possible, that you will get errors when you add this annotation if you use the JavaSDK 1.5 as this annotation was added for non-Interface methods with JavaSDK 1.6.

To enforce the generation or at least the error in Eclipse that the method is missing, you need to make the method abstract in your parent class. If you have done that, your IDE should assist you in generating the method and it should also add the annotation.

Comment: Thanks Warren , Awesome Answer .. This is the missing thing **'abstract for method too'** I thought it was enough for class

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on the question that you're asking.

You can override your methods, this means not changing the return type but changing the method implementation, although the return type can be more specific.

Comment: I mean : Like **'@Override'** with onclick() or onBackPressed()

**Example :** I just made my "class extends Async" And the doInbackground generate as override method ..